# 'Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' not read all the rows from .xlsx file on server (IIS7)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, oledb, web-deployment

I know that is this question has dozen of answers and posts, but nothing works for me.

We have my MVC4 application and i deployed it to IIS7 to my server and one more machine where we don't have visual studio installed.

We are doing import/export data from/to excel for doing bulk entry.

we do have data around 20000 in one sheet with .xlsx format of Office 2007(File is save as Excel Work book).

Now when i read data by using following code it just read data around 4000-5000 rows only.

This whole below code ***working fine in my local machine where i do code and read all 20000 rows data from "Excel 97-2003 Workbook with .xls"*** 
but not working with "Excel Workbook with .xlsx".

```
private void FillDataSet(HttpPostedFileBase file, DataSet ds)
{
  using (
    var con =
      new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" File Path";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"))
  {
      con.Open();
      var dtSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
      var strSheetName = "";
      strSheetName = dtSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();          
      var cmd = new OleDbCommand();
  var da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
  cmd.Connection = con;
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + strSheetName + "]";
  da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
  da.Fill(ds);        
  }
}
```

I have gone through the below steps and solutions but it's not working for me.

-Installing Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable.

-Installing 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components

we are confuse why it is working on my local machine and not working on server.

Please provide any idea or solution for this issue..

What I have tried:
-From the solution explorer right-click your project then click Properties.
-Click the Build tab
-Change Platform target from: Any CPU to x86 | Any CPU to x64
-Re-build your solution
-Also made changes on IIS in Advance setting with Enable 32-Bit application as True/False.

- Also tried all connection strings from this link.
  https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/

Comment: I have same problem, if you found any solution please share with us.

Answer (score 2):

some time while reading the data from excel you need to convert all the data into Text Format

**OLD Connection String**

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" File Path";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"
```

**Updated Connection string**

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" File Path";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';"
```

This will convert your all data into Text format all the data will be displayed.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
private void FillDataSet(HttpPostedFileBase file, DataSet ds)
{
  using (
    var con =
      new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" File Path";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';"))
  {
      con.Open();
      var dtSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
      var strSheetName = "";
      strSheetName = dtSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();          
      var cmd = new OleDbCommand();
  var da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
  cmd.Connection = con;
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + strSheetName + "]";
  da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
  da.Fill(ds);        
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tanay for update..
but that is also not resolved my issue.
i have gone through the connection stirngs given by this link but in any case it is not read whole 20000 records
It's just read 4000-5000 records only with .xlsx format
https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/

Comment: This is not right. IMEX=1 means that the provider will treat mixed colums as text not that it treats everything as text. Sadly the provider will still scan the first 8 rows and make decisions on the data types in the columns. Without IMEX=1 it would return Null for everything that was not evaluated to the data type it settles on. This is not an issue if it evaluates them to Text anyway but if it thinks they are numbers then you'll get Nulls in the Text cells. In this case IMEX=1 will return text for columns where there are mixed data types in the first 8 cells of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I had some problems as well.

```
  new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source;Data Source=" File Path";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";))
```

Comment: The Jet provider is obsolete and should never be used any more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The program worked fine in my local/SIT environment, but I couldn't read all of the Excel rows. And it would not allow for me to change the platform target from *Any CPU* to *x86 | x64*. My production environment worked find on Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS8 when reading Excel files (`.xlsx`).

I was able to fix this with following steps:

1. Check the IIS application pool > *Advanced Settings* > *Enable 32-bit applications* True | False. (I think this lead the program to use the x32 | x64 bit driver)
2. Search your *ODBC Data Sources* and check the related x32 | x64 driver. And upgrade the driver from v12 to v14 (remove *Access Database Engine 2007*, install *Access Database Engine 2010*)
3. Connection String: `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=FilePath;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;"`